# Generate an orthonormal basis belonging to a plan defined by it normal vector.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let's call $P$ the plan that passes by one point $P_0 = (x_0, y_0, z_0)$ and have $n = (n_x, n_y, n_z)$ it normal vector.

My main objective is to find the rotation matrix that $A_1 = rotation(A_0, r)$ where $r$ is desired angle in radiant. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle) is pretty well documented for that.

So for in order to generate a orthonormal basis $(u, v)$, I don't know where to start. I thought that finding the first one, $u$,  is the hardest because after I just need to compute the cross product between $n$ and $u$ but how to find the first one ? And then divide $u$ and $v$ by their magnitude.

One solution might be to find another point, $P_1$ in the plan that is not $P_0$ and then find $u = (x_1-x_0, y_1-y_0, z_1-z_0)$. But what generic method can give me one $P_1$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand a bit on [Aretino’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2373816/265466), at least two of $(0,0,1)\times n=(-n_y,n_x,0)$, $(0,1,0)\times n=(n_z,0,-n_x)$, $(1,0,0)\times n=(0,-n_z,n_y)$ must be non-zero and parallel to the plane (do you see why?). Choose any one of those non-zero vectors as the second vector of your basis.

Then normalize these two vectors to produce an orthonormal basis.

Comment: Thanks @amd, I must admit that it looks obscure of where those values come from. In particular why always inserting a $-$ sign ?

Comment: @Deewy They’re the cross products of the normal with the unit coordinate basis vectors. Even if you don’t spot that, you should be able to see that when you take the dot product of one of these vectors with the normal, you ”cross multiply” two of the coordinates of the normal with each other. The minus sign ensures that the dot product then vanishes.

Comment: Ok, I still don't get it sorry. We have this normal arbitrary vector about a plane. How can a cross product between the unit coordinate basis vector (the classical $(0,0,0)$ and $(i, j, k)$ can give you a vector in the plan ? For me this would mean that $i, j$ or $k$ are parallel to the plane.

Comment: @Deewy By definition, the cross product of two vectors is orthogonal to both of them. Also by definition, the normal to a plane is orthogonal to it, and so to every vector parallel to that plane. You’re working in three dimensions, so the *only* vectors orthogonal to the normal are parallel to the plane. Try one out for yourself: what’s $(n_x,n_y,n_z)\times(1,0,0)$?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and all your explanations. It's clear now that in a general way $crossproduct(a,b)$ is orthogonal to $c$ with $b$ orthogonal to $c$.

Answer (score 0):

An obvious choice could be $u=(-n_y,n_x,0)$, provided $n_y$ and $n_x$ are not both vanishing, in which case the choice is even easier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Aretino.